# what are the default service behaviors on ServiceModel.Routing?

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-routing

**What are the default service behaviors on ServiceModel.Routing?**

I'm not talking about the Azure stuff I mean these Interfaces from

**System.ServiceModel.Routing**

- IDuplexSessionRouter
- IRequestReplyRouter
- ISimplexDatagramRouter
- ISimplexSessionRouter

I understand about picking the correct 'binding' for the desired context at the actual service endpoint that's doing the work,....

(I.E. the service that this router (hand-rolled-service_bus) is actually going to route *(by EndPointName)* messages to)

*(there will of course be several services, in the future that are routed per the callers supplied ---EndPointName--- to various services)*

...but how are Concurrency and Instance modes handled by these routing "contracts" at this middle layer **THE Routing service** that implements one or more of these System.ServiceModel.Routing Namespace Interfaces?!

Am I over thinking this and these Routing Contracts (Interfaces) just pass the messages through? As I type this I wonder if I should perhaps actually create a class that inherits the desired routing interface/contract and try to manually apply my desired service behaviors, like one would a **normal** WCF Interface...

All the examples have been just "using" these routing interfaces not creating a class that implements one of them and tacking on service behaviors thereafter.

Answer (score 0):

The "Routing Service" just passes messages through to the target service based on the routing table.

According to the `System.ServiceModel.Routing.dll, v4.0.0.0` assembly, the interface is defined with 
`InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession` definition included below:

```
namespace System.ServiceModel.Routing
{
    // Summary:
    //     Defines the routing service, which is responsible for routing messages between
    //     endpoints based on filter criteria.
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    [ServiceBehavior(AddressFilterMode = AddressFilterMode.Any, InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession, UseSynchronizationContext = false, ValidateMustUnderstand = false)]
    public sealed class RoutingService : ISimplexDatagramRouter, ISimplexSessionRouter, IRequestReplyRouter, IDuplexSessionRouter, IDisposable
    {
    }
}
```